# error while loading shared libraries: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when launching game

Tags: libraries

I am trying to run MCPE on Linux, I've set everything up, but when I run the game I get this error:

```
/tmp/.mount_MinecrC0c2NX/usr/bin/./mcpelauncher-client: error while loading shared libraries: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Process exited with unexpected exit code: 127
```

I've tried installing libegl1:i386, but I get another error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libegl-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit

Comment: You've gotten yourself into "dependency hell". You will hzve to install `libEGL`'s dependencies, their dependencies, their dependencies,  ... . Keep going, there" s an end eventually.

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-10-base : Breaks: gcc-10-base:i386 (!= 10.1.0-1) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-10-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-10-base (!= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.1.0-1 is to be installed`

I've tried to do that and got this

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` , `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f` .

Comment: @N0rbert I did that and it just gave me a list of packages that were automatically installed and are no longer required

Comment: Then it is time for `sudo apt-get install libegl1:i386` .

Comment: @N0rbert I did that already, its in the question

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it myself. My friend told me to use aptitude to install the packages, so I ran `sudo aptitude install libegl1:i386`, then I used `sudo aptitude install libc6-i386 libx11-6:i386 libegl1-mesa:i386 zlib1g:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libasound2:i386 libpulse0:i386`